# Should I hold a grudge against my ex-colleagues?

Tags: colleagues

I was let go at my company, as I did 'fit in with the culture'. I'm not too worried about being fired, as I've already gotten a job offer, however, during my time at the company my ex-team acted like they really cared forming a 'friendship' with me, but that changed when I was let go.

1) My line manager did not even respond to my pleas of asking for a reference 
2) I did not get a single message from my ex-team (heard that they took the last guy that was let go for drinks)

Comment: VtC: Whether you "hold a grudge" or not is a personal decision and since you will not see them ever again as far as we know, the outcome of that decision has no influence on the workplace.

Comment: They have decided to burn bridges with you, so move on, and if you ever bump into them, you know what kind of people they are and act accordingly (but stay professional then).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because holding a grudge is not a workplace issue

Comment: @jmoreno What a loser, spending his X-Mas on this forum lmao, trying to get questions closed.

Comment: All of the votes to close are answers, saying “no”. Holding a grudge against people you will never see isn’t going to help you at your new workplace. Unless you’re a writer and need characters to die in horrible and amusing ways, then go for it.

Answer (score 12):

No. Grudges are almost never productive - especially since you've already moved on to another job.

Answer (score 7):

What are you hoping that holding a grudge will accomplish? Do you think you'll feel better if you're being angry and negative towards them all the time? Do you think wallowing in sad thoughts is going to improve your life and help your carreer? Do you think they'll feel worse? Hell, do you think they'll even *care*?

There's no point to holding a grudge. As is said; holding a grudge is like drinking poison and waiting for the other person to die. It's a waste of your time and energy.

Go do something positive and productive with it instead.